# Call function in a subfolder

Tags: go, module, package

Files structure:

```
main folder--main.go

|--Utils

inside Utils: Read-Words.go
```

So. I would like to use the functions inside Read-words.go in main.go.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Read How to Write Go Code and take the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Read-Word.go set the package like parent folder on the top of file. So if that file on Utils folder. the package is Utils. Example :

```
package Utils
```

I suggest to give the folder name to not using a capital. Therefore your code like `package utils` . So, when you want to use the function on Read-Word.go, you could call the function like :

```
utils.<name_of_fuction>
```

Example :

```
utils.FindWord() // or etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. NOw I added a second file .go in Utils. BUt now the main doesn't recognize this second file.